# Record audio while recording OpenGL view

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I have an OpenGL view of which I am recording a video using what is explained in [this](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673) great blog post. In addition to that, I would like to record audio from the microphone and mix it with the video.

The first solution I came up with was something like this (I've ommited some code for the sake of clarity):

```
writer = [[AVAssetWriter alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:&error];

audioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio outputSettings:audioOutputSettings]; 
videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio outputSettings:videoSettings];

[writer addInput:audioWriterInput];
[writer addInput:videoWriterInput];
[writer startWriting];
```

I create two inputs, one audio, one video, and start writing. Every time a frame is rendered, I get a snapshot of the OpenGL view, convert it to a `CVPixelBufferRef` and add it to the writer input using a `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`:

```
CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
float millisecondsElapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startRecordingDate] * 1000.0;
buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[shot CGImage] size:shot.size];  
BOOL addedToBuffer = [bufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(millisecondsElapsed, 1000)];
```

Now my problem is that I don't know how to get the audio packets from the microphone into the `AVAssetWriterInput` and I wouldn't know how to sync both properly. I've been looking at `AVAssetReader`, but it can't figure out how to get the audio from the microphone. Also I thought about reading from the file which `AVAudioRecorder` writes to, but I don't know how to read from it and convert those packets to a `CMSampleBufferRef`. Which then would be the input for the `AVAssetWriterInput`.

I hope someone can point me towards the right solution. Any suggestions or directions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm doing is:

1. Record the audio with AVAudioRecorder into a file.
2. Use a AVMutableComposition for joining the video and the audio tracks.
3. Read the video into an AVURLAsset variable.
4. Read the audio file into an AVURLAsset variable.
5. Add each AVURLAsset into an AVMutableCompositionTrack.
6. Export the composition and voilà...

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that and it just worked, thanks! However I am looking for a way to mix both while recording, I'll wait a little longer in case someone has the answer, otherwise I'll accept you answer.

Comment: For that case I'm afraid you won't be able to capture audio using AVAudioRecorder. That class always records the audio into a file. You'd need to store the audio in memory and make the composition on the fly, or something like that. Don't know if that's possible. Have you had a look to iOS SpeakHere example?